# How to specify Dockerrun.aws.json for AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I am attempting to host a Docker application with AWS via Elastic Beanstalk. When going through manual creation of an environment I am given the option to run a sample application in the environment, upload my own, or pull an application off of s3. By uploading a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file with all the necessary configuration the environment is able to pull and run my Docker image.

Now I am using Terraform to programmatically create and configure these environments. However, upon creation they all run the sample application, which in turn causes problems when I attempt to manually upload the Dockerrun file to the environment.

What is the proper way to include the Dockerrun information in the Terraform configuration so my application can deploy without a hitch?

Answer (score 2):

You should use an S3 bucket to store the `Dockerrun.aws.json` and set up a Beanstalk application version.

Something like:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "latest" {
  name        = "latest"
  application = "your_app"
  bucket      = "your_bucket"
  key         = "Dockerrun.aws.json"
}
```

Then add to your Beanstalk environment:

```
version_label = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.latest.name}"
```

Of course, is better to use references instead of hardcoding names.

Comment: Is it also possible to upload the json file as part of `terraform apply`?

Comment: sure, add a bucket object resource and use references in the ElasticBeanstalk https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_object.html